# Syntax error when returning boolean value

Tags: python

Im writing a function to check for a winner in a tictactoe game.

My intent is to return true or false if these spaces are covered in the game to determine a winner.
It's returning me a [syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brj9h.png) after the first or. Where am I going wrong in writing this?

```
def is_winner(board_spaces, letter):
return 
(board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[1] == letter) or
(board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[4] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
(board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[8] == letter) or
(board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[6] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter) or
(board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
(board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter)
```

Comment: You can't extend a statement across multiple lines like that unless you (a) use `\\` to escape the end-of-line or (b) put line breaks inside of parenthesized expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not get errors, write your whole statement in one line instead of the line break.

If you want lines to break, you can use `\` before the line break. See the following code.

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + \
            num2

print(add(10, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the enter from your return statement

```
return (statement_1)or(statement_2)...
```

```
return (board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[1] == letter) or
(board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[4] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
(board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[8] == letter) or
(board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[6] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter) or
(board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
(board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

your missing a bracket

```
def is_winner(board_spaces, letter):
    return \
    (
    (board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[1] == letter) or
    (board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[4] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
    (board_spaces[2] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[8] == letter) or
    (board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[6] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter) or
    (board_spaces[3] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[7] == letter) or
    (board_spaces[1] == letter and board_spaces[5] == letter and board_spaces[9] == letter))
```

With these extra brackets you say to the return statement that you give one final answer and not choose between "a or b"

Also you can use `\` to contine on the following row to let python know you are not done with that row in syntax

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you cannot break a statement into multiple lines as you did.

I'd suggest an improvement that is easier to read and write. List of indicies is incomplete as it is just an example.

```py
indices_to_match = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 7], [3, 6, 9]]

def is_winner(board_spaces, letter):
    return any([
        all([board_spaces[space] == letter
             for space in row])
        for row in indices_to_match])
```

What is nice about this is that it separates the list of indices from the rest of the code, making it more readable.

Please also note that Python lists are zero-based, so the first index is 0.